# Shell_Exec error for directory listing?

Tags: php, image, shell-exec

I found a useful php code which displays the photos in a folder directory as a image preview. The issue is my host provider blocks one of the script commands, "Shell_exec()", so the php code doesn't work.

Any way of getting the code to run without using shell_exec?

```
<?PHP
  // filetypes to display
  $imagetypes = array("image/jpeg", "image/gif");
?>
<?PHP

  function getImages($dir)
  {
    global $imagetypes;

    // array to hold return value
    $retval = array();

    // add trailing slash if missing
    if(substr($dir, -1) != "/") $dir .= "/";

    // full server path to directory
    $fulldir = "{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/$dir";

    $d = @dir($fulldir) or die("getImages: Failed opening directory $dir for reading");
    while(false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
      // skip hidden files
      if($entry[0] == ".") continue;

      // check for image files
      $f = escapeshellarg("$fulldir$entry");
      $mimetype = trim(`file -bi $f`);
      foreach($imagetypes as $valid_type) {
        if(preg_match("@^{$valid_type}@", $mimetype)) {
          $retval[] = array(
           'file' => "/$dir$entry",
           'size' => getimagesize("$fulldir$entry")
          );
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    $d->close();

    return $retval;
  }
?>
<?PHP
  // fetch image details
  $images = getImages("images");

  // display on page
  foreach($images as $img) {
    echo "<div class=\"photo\">";
    echo "<img src=\"{$img['file']}\" {$img['size'][3]} alt=\"\"><br>\n";
    // display image file name as link
    echo "<a href=\"{$img['file']}\">",basename($img['file']),"</a><br>\n";
    // display image dimenstions
    echo "({$img['size'][0]} x {$img['size'][1]} pixels)<br>\n";
    // display mime_type
    echo $img['size']['mime'];
    echo "</div>\n";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Your question is really confusing, can you please elaborate what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: I don't see any reason to use shell_exec(). There are php functions to scan a directory. Just look through the php.net manual.

Comment: Maybe I'm going senile, but where's the `shell_exec`?

Comment: Nevermind, found it, it's using backticks instead of explicit `shell_exec`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mime type of a file using the PHP function mime_content_type(). This way you can get rid of the shell_execute used to detect the mime type in your code.